# Set up NFS with ddev: /Volumes/Sites

Tags: docker, nfs, ddev

I would like to set up nfs as described on https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/performance/ to (hopefully) speed up ddev performance on my mac.

Now the instruction is to set `nfs_mount_enabled: true` in config.yaml (✔check) AND run this script: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drud/ddev/master/scripts/macos_ddev_nfs_setup.sh – correct?

I don't understand the part about export, Users etc.

My sites live on a separate volume (Case sensitive): `/Volumes/Sites`

(How) do I have to adapt the setup script?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change the script, just edit /etc/exports to export /Volumes/Sites.
The script created a line that shares /Users, just imitate that and add a new line, copy it exactly, but change the share.

So the script created a line in /etc/exports like this:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/<your-username>-alldirs -mapall=<your_uid>:20 localhost
```

(for the main Volume, Catalina requires the path `/System/Volumes/Data/`)

Copy that line and edit it as such:

```
/Volumes/Sites -alldirs -mapall=<your_uid>:20 localhost
```

And then restart nfsd with `sudo nfsd restart`

Comment: Thanks! Is it correct that this is *in addition* to running the script? 
I've added the info to a PR for the docs https://github.com/drud/ddev/pull/2164, but maybe it needs some refinement still

Comment: Something's wrong with the path; I get: `ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-sgch_nfsmount/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/Sites/mysite:/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-sgch_nfsmount/_data, data: addr=192.168.65.2,hard,nolock: no such file or directory 
Encountered errors while bringing up the project. `

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it: only for the "Macintosh HD" /System/Volumes/Data has to be prepended. 

`/Volumes/Sites -alldirs -mapall=123:20 localhost 
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/username -alldirs -mapall=123:20 localhost`

Comment: Sorry @rfay I still got a doubt: now the local path (WITH the long stuff `device: ":/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/Sites/sgch-craft`)  has been added to `docker-compose.yaml` – should that file be committed to git at all?

Comment: docker-compose.yaml is ddev-generated and should never be commited. It's excluded by .ddev/.gitignore.